# Unable to LOAD from XML: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm having difficulty loading records from XML on OSX using the command

```
load xml local infile 'records.xml'
into table Badges
rows identified by '<row>';
```

and I keep getting the error:

```
Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version   0.00017 sec
```

I've checked `` SHOW VARIABLES WHERE `Variable_name` = 'local_infile'; `` and it's `ON`. I've also set it explicitly with `SET GLOBAL local_infile = true;`. Anyone know why this is happening? I'm using mysql 5.7.

Comment: Remove [LOCAL] keyword - the file you want to import is already local one.

Comment: @Akina I use the `local` keyword to get around the `secure-file-priv` issue.

Comment: The error message which you obtain can have a lot of reasons. 1) LOCAL is disabled on the server side. Check `local-infile = 1` in the [mysqld] section of .ini file. 2) LOCAL is disabled on the client side. Check `loose-local-infile = 1` in the [client] section of .ini file. 3) The server variable `local_infile` is set to FALSE (or 0). Check `select @@local_infile;` output. 4) There is no enough permissions or free space for to copy the file into the directory set in  `secure-file-priv` server variable. Check. 5) The MySQL account used for importing have no `FILE` privilege. Check.

Comment: @Akina I've only managed to resolve it by restarting the server with `secure-file-priv` disabled.